# Target group health check for ECS service failing upon creation with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I've been hosting an api as a service on ecs with an alb. Whenver the service is running it fails the health check and continually kills and restarts the task. The task logs always show it repsonding to the health checks with response 200 so it should be passing. I've checked that my security groups and vpc's are configured correctly. I will post my cloud formation template below in hopes someone can find my mistake. I've also tried increasing the health check graces period greatly and it hasn't helped the issue.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "6514f997-7e0a-48c6-9e5f-95465c35ff00": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 280,
                    "y": 140
                },
                "z": 0,
                "embeds": []
            }
        }
    },
    "Parameters": {
        "ClusterName": {
            "Type" : "String",
            "Description" : "Name of the ECS Cluster",
            "Default" : "Rest-Api-Explorer"
        },
        "Subnet": {
            "Description": "User Specified Subnet",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
            "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid Subnet of specified VPC."
        }
    },
    "Mappings" : {
        "SubnetToVPCMap" : {
            "subnet-58863c01" : {"VPC" : "vpc-6581f100"},
            "subnet-ae349ec6" : {"VPC" : "vpc-259a344d"},
            "subnet-b9349ed1" : {"VPC" : "vpc-259a344d"},
            "subnet-d8349eb0" : {"VPC" : "vpc-259a344d"},
            "subnet-e9b7d69e" : {"VPC" : "vpc-6581f100"},
            "subnet-ee97d48b" : {"VPC" : "vpc-6581f100"}
        },
        "VPCToSecurityGroupMap" : {
            "vpc-6581f100" : {"SecurityGroup" : "sg-a5c672c1"},
            "vpc-259a344d" : {"SecurityGroup" : "sg-1d658072"}
        },
        "VPCToTag" : {
            "vpc-6581f100" : {"Tag" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": "Rest API Explorer"}, {"Key": "Type", "Value": "Development"}]},
            "vpc-259a344d" : {"Tag" : [{ "Key": "Name", "Value": "Rest API Explorer"}, {"Key": "Type", "Value": "Production"}]}
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "ECSCluster":{
            "Type" : "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
            "Properties" : {
                "ClusterName" : {"Ref" : "ClusterName"},
                "Tags": {
                    "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "VPCToTag", {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetToVPCMap", {"Ref" : "Subnet"}, "VPC"]} , "Tag"]
                }
            }
        },
        "EC2Instance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "IamInstanceProfile": "ecsInstanceRole",
                "ImageId": "ami-00e0090ac21971297",
                "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
                "KeyName": "community-admin",
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "VPCToSecurityGroupMap", {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetToVPCMap", {"Ref" : "Subnet"}, "VPC"]} , "SecurityGroup"]}
                ],
                "SubnetId": {
                    "Ref": "Subnet"
                },
                "Tags": {
                    "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "VPCToTag", {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetToVPCMap", {"Ref" : "Subnet"}, "VPC"]} , "Tag"]
                },
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                                "echo ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref" : "ClusterName" },
                                " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "6514f997-7e0a-48c6-9e5f-95465c35ff00"
                }
            }
        },
        "ECSALB":{
          "Type":"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
          "Properties":{
            "Name":"rest-api-explorer-2",
            "Scheme":"internal",
            "LoadBalancerAttributes": [
              {
                "Key":"idle_timeout.timeout_seconds",
                "Value":"60"
              }
            ],
            "SecurityGroups":[
              {
                "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "VPCToSecurityGroupMap", {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetToVPCMap", {"Ref" : "Subnet"}, "VPC"]} , "SecurityGroup"]
              }
            ],
            "Subnets" : [
                "subnet-58863c01",
                "subnet-e9b7d69e",
                "subnet-ee97d48b"
            ]
          }
        },
        "ALBListener":{
            "Type":"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "DependsOn": "ECSTG",
            "Properties":{
              "DefaultActions":[
                {
                  "Type":"forward",
                  "TargetGroupArn":{
                    "Ref":"ECSTG"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "LoadBalancerArn":{
                "Ref":"ECSALB"
              },
              "Port":"80",
              "Protocol":"HTTP"
            }
        },
        "ECSTG":{
            "Type":"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "DependsOn":"ECSALB",
            "Properties":{
              "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds":15,
              "HealthCheckPath":"/api/rest/console",              
              "HealthCheckPort":"traffic-port",
              "HealthCheckProtocol":"HTTP",
              "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds":10,
              "HealthyThresholdCount":3,
              "Name":"rest-api-target-group-2",
              "Port":3000,
              "Protocol":"HTTP",
              "TargetType":"ip",
              "UnhealthyThresholdCount":5,
              "VpcId":{
                "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetToVPCMap", {"Ref" : "Subnet"}, "VPC"]
              }
            }
        },
        "service":{
            "Type":"AWS::ECS::Service",
            "DependsOn": "ALBListener",
            "Properties":{
              "Cluster":{
                "Ref":"ECSCluster"
              },
              "DeploymentConfiguration": {
                "MaximumPercent": 100,
                "MinimumHealthyPercent": 0
              },
              "DesiredCount":"1",
              "HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds" : 90,
              "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
              "LoadBalancers":[
                {
                  "ContainerName":"api-rest-explorer",
                  "ContainerPort":"3000",
                  "TargetGroupArn":{
                    "Ref":"ECSTG"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "NetworkConfiguration": {
                  "AwsvpcConfiguration" : {
                    "AssignPublicIp" : "ENABLED",
                    "SecurityGroups" : [
                      {
                        "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "VPCToSecurityGroupMap", {"Fn::FindInMap" : [ "SubnetToVPCMap", {"Ref" : "Subnet"}, "VPC"]} , "SecurityGroup"]
                      }
                    ],
                    "Subnets" : [
                      {"Ref": "Subnet"}
                    ]
                  }
              },
              "SchedulingStrategy": "REPLICA",
              "ServiceName" : "rest-api-explorer-fargate",
              "TaskDefinition": "rest-api-explorer-fargate:4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question. Your `"ContainerPort":"3000"` and TargetGroup Protocol is sending on `"Port":80`. Shouldn't they be in sync?.

Comment: Yep you're totally right. I made that change yesterday in hopes of fixing the failed health checks, but it is still behaving the same way :(. thanks for the pointer though

Comment: Can you update the question with updated one?. Now it comes down is whether your service is up and running before health check is performed. Your `UnhealthyThresholdCount` is 2 so maybe health check already failed and your service came after that. Try to increase your [healthCheckGracePeriodSeconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html).

Comment: Okay I've updated it now

Comment: Everything looks ok in template. Last thing comes to my mind is whether your app responding to health checks fine. You mentioned, you can see health check calls in app logs and they are 200. Are you sure they are coming from TargetGroup?. If your ECS Task Definition also has health checks then ECS agent performs its own health checks in addition to TargetGroup. Please check once whether your app health check is performing fine(usually, this is the cause). Also, check whether your service security group allows inbound traffic from ALB Target Group Security group.